# Angular: failed to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, client-side

So I am just starting up with Angular and for some reason angular is throwing an error saying my module is unavailable.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=plopApp

Here is my code so far: (super basic with no real functionality)

```
@section scripts{
<script src="/Scripts/branding/views.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

<h2>Branding Management</h2>
<div ng-app="plopApp">
    <div ng-controller="BrandingController">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Seperate views.js

```
(function () {
    var mod = angular.module('plopApp', []);

mod.controller('BrandingController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I forgot to add that my project does reference the angular libraries

Answer (score 2):

You never actually call the function that wraps the call to `angular.module`.

```
(function () {
    var mod = angular.module('plopApp', []);

    mod.controller('BrandingController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
    }]);
})() // parentheses call this function
```

I would also say that this wrapping is unnecessary since you don't need to assign to `mod` and can also use `angular.module('plopApp')` to read it, but there is nothing inherently wrong with this style either.

Comment: This worked. So stylistically which lends itself better to extensibility?